# Is pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch contain openni_node.launch?

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [recognition kitchen--ROS Quick Guide](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/ros_quickguide.html).

It says I need to run:

```
  roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

But I want to run object_recognition package in gazebo.

So I found that the pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch file:

```
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch
```

Is pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch contain all the same functionalities of openni_node.launch?

If no, how to simulate the kinect which can be used in package which needs to run openni_node.launch?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42071/is-pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch-contain-openni_node.launch?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is a [openni plugin](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp) that pr2 simulation uses to generate topics published by the kinect; it's mostly there, but there are some issues that need to be sorted out.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-23**:
What's their difference? What issue I need to take care and how? Thank you~